# Why is the bilinear form on $H^d(X,\mathbb Q_{\ell})$ afforded by Poincaré duality alternating when $d = \dim(X)$ is odd?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, poincare-duality

Let $X$ be a smooth projective irreducible variety of pure dimension $d$ over an algebraically closed field of positive characteristic $p$. Let $\ell \not = p$ be a prime number. There is an isomorphism $\mathrm{Tr}: H^{2d}(X,\mathbb Q_{\ell}) \xrightarrow{\sim} \mathbb Q_{\ell}(-d)$, and cup-product define a pairing
$$\mathrm{Tr}(x\cup y): H^i(X,\mathbb Q_{\ell}) \times H^{2d-i}(X,\mathbb Q_{\ell}) \to \mathbb Q_{\ell}(-d).$$
Poincaré duality states that this pairing is perfect.

In particular, for $i = d$ we obtain a bilinear form on $H^d(X,\mathbb Q_{\ell})$. In *La conjecture de Weil: I* (1974), Deligne writes that if $d$ is odd, this pairing is alternating (cf. paragraph 2.6).

I don't understand where this property comes from. I thought that cup product on $H^d(X,\mathbb Q_{\ell})$ was commutative, ie. $x \cup y = y \cup x$. If the form were alternating, it would be in particular skew-symmetric, ie. $\mathrm{Tr}(x \cup y) = - \mathrm{Tr}(y \cup x)$. This is impossible if cup-product really is commutative. What would be the explanation?

Comment: The cup product is graded commutative, not commutative.

Comment: @KentaS Ok, so that's the thing. Thank you very much, I'm ashamed to say that I actually didn't know about this terminology. You may post your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with singular cohomology, the cup product is *graded* commutative, not commutative. This means that for $x\in H^p(X,\mathbb Q_\ell)$ and $y\in H^q(X,\mathbb Q_\ell)$,
$$x\cup y=(-1)^{pq}y\cup x\in H^{p+q}(X,\mathbb Q_\ell).$$